# How to upload to blob container from Job Release Task in Azure Batch .net

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

I need to upload files to Blob Container in Azure batch service. I know I can do that in CloudTask using OutpuFiles but I want to do that in JobRelease Task. I cant figure out how can I do that. I am using C# SDK for azure batch.

Answer (score -1):

We don’t currently support OutputFiles on JobPrep/JobRelease tasks, although it is on the roadmap I’m not sure when it’s scheduled for.

In the meantime there are a few workarounds but they all basically boil down to running the upload yourself in your task. For example you could use the File Conventions C# SDK, or you could just use the Azure Storage SDK directly.
Alternatively you could use a tool such as AzCopy and specify your commandLine like so: “myCommandLine && AzCopy ”

Else, continue with the process you are using for now.

Answer also posted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7507434-907e-4ee1-b0ae-da7dcdbe0493/how-to-upload-to-blob-container-from-job-release-task-in-azure-batch-net?forum=azurebatch